# Connect to External Mongo

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is it possible to connect to an external mongo db or some other no sql database to get some data?

I don't mean to have no sql database as the main joomla installation. Joomla is installed to mariadb but I need to get data from third no sql database preferable mongo db.

Is it possible?

I haven't found any tutorial on this.

Comment: Welcome to JSE Christoforos.  While you wait for feedback, please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but this falls outside of the Joomla realm and you'll need to develop it yourself.

Here's a starting point for MongoDB drivers in PHP: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_php.htm